# How to use Anaconda python in Apache storm shell bolt

Tags: python, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am trying to run Apache storm topology with Python bolt using shell bolt.
In my bolt i am using spacy library which i have installed in /home/labuser/anaconda3/bin/python.
However when i run topology storm displays error message module not found spacy.
After debugging i found that storm is using python 2.7 located in /usr/bin/python .

My question is an extension to question below,
[In storm, how to specify specific version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859335/in-storm-how-to-specify-specific-version-of-python?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

as per answer in the question above i tried to create shell bolt using   super("home/labuser/anaconda3/bin/python", "splitsentence.py"); constructor but yet storm continues to pick up 2.7 in /usr/bin/python dir.

I need to know how i could tell storm to use python3 in home/labuser/anaconda3/bin/python directory for my shell bolt.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that specifying which python version to use **in constructor of shell bolt** of implementation is the answer.I had tried this one initially but due to some other build issues it was failing.I did a fresh build and now it works.

```
public static class SplitSentence extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public SplitSentence() {
      super("home/labuser/anaconda3/bin/python", "splitsentence.py");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

all thanks to this answer
[In storm, how to specify specific version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859335/in-storm-how-to-specify-specific-version-of-python?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

If you have any other issues make sure to read 
http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Multilang-protocol.html